# Laravel: webhooks need to bypass Laravel's CSRF verification

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

In two places I have found that Laravel csrf protection can be bypassed by setting the `protected $except` variable. But its not seems to be working according to the doc:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/billing#handling-stripe-webhooks

and in

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection

```
protected $except = [
    'stripe/*',
];
```

I'm using 5.1

Here is in routes.php

```
Route::match(['post'], '/webhooks/provider/callback/{version}', [
    'as' => 'provider.webhooks.callback', 'uses' => 'WebhookController@callback'
]);
Route::match(['post'], '/webhooks/provider/fallback/{version}', [
    'as' => 'provider.webhooks.fallback', 'uses' => 'WebhookController@fallback'
]);
```

And here is the

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {
    protected $except = [
        'webhooks/*',
        '/webhooks/*',
    ];
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }
}
```

And here is what in the `BaseVerifier` where I am not seeing any `$except` check:

```
<?php namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter;
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\StringUtils;
class VerifyCsrfToken implements Middleware {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request))
        {
            return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
        }

        throw new TokenMismatchException;
    }
}
```

However I had solved by commenting out but still setting the `$except` should have been worked according to the doc; isn't it?:

```
<?php namespace App\Http;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;
class Kernel extends HttpKernel {
    protected $middleware = [
        //'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
    ];
}
```

And here is in the error log:

```
[2015-07-06 09:40:34] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:46
Stack trace:
#0 /app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(125): App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
```

Comment: Can you post your routes file? Have you set the route as '/stripe/webhook'?

Comment: And are you using Laravel 5.1?

Comment: yes its 5.1 @TheShiftExchange

Comment: And can you post your routes?

Comment: Are you sure its 5.1? Because that BaseVerifer is from 5.0 - not 5.1

Comment: @TheShiftExchange You are correct. Its from 5.0. I am so sorry that I have messed up with multiple projects and multiple versions. I am using 4.2, 5.0, & 5.1 altogether recently. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
//add an array of Routes to skip CSRF check
private $openRoutes = ['free/route', 'free/too'];

//modify this function
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //add this condition 
    foreach($this->openRoutes as $route) {

      if ($request->is($route)) {
        return $next($request);
      }
    }

    return parent::handle($request, $next);
  }
```

[source](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/disable-csrf-on-specific-routes)

In the `$openRoutes` array gives your routes and this will be bypassed.

Comment: This is *only* if they are using `Laravel 5.0`. If they are using `Laravel 5.1` this is no needed

Answer (score 1):

So for Laravel 5.0 you can use this ;

```
private $openRoutes = ['webhooks/free', 'webhooks/*'];

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   if(in_array($request->path(), $this->openRoutes)){
    return $next($request);
   }

    return parent::handle($request, $next);
}
```

for Laravel 5.1 you can user this feature

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
 /**
 * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $except = [
                       'stripe/*',
                     ];
 }
```

source on the doc
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-excluding-uris

Answer (score 0):

If you place your webhooks routes in `web.php` or any other route files, they will require `CSRF` token. Alternatively, You should place your webhooks routes inside `routes/api.php` because this file doesn't require `CSRF` token validation and routes inside `api.php` won't be validated through `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.
Have a look inside `boot` method in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider` you will find:

```php
        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
```

This means that `web` routes are protected using middleware group called `web` while `api` routes are protected using middleware group called `api` and both are defined inside `app/Http/Kernel.php`, if you have a look inside that file, you fill find that `web` routes are protected using `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware which causes CSRF verification error while `api` routes don't have this middleware

```php
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            ...,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            ...,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```